# Show array of image from server in image carahousal

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

hey guys im using react native ImageCarahousal in that. I want to show my array of image in this they can be multiple or many . I need to show that in my imagecarahousal... 
that is showing normally static image like this `[{uri:'https://images.pexels.com/photos/889087/pexels-photo-889087.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260'}]`
 how can I make it based on array of multiple images

```
<ImageCarousel
                 height={300}
                 delay={7000}
                 animate= "true"
                 indicatorSize={10}
                 indicatorColor="white"
                 images={
    [this.props.navigation.state.params.itemimage.map
        ( ( item,i)=> {
                              {uri:item}
                            } ) ]
               }
                 />
```

Comment: `itemimage` is what type of object?

Comment: this is string type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
 <ImageCarousel
                     height={300}
                     delay={7000}
                     animate= "true"
                     indicatorSize={10}
                     indicatorColor="white"
                     images={params.itemimage && params.itemimage.map(item => {uri:item})}
/>
```